# Create a directory to web opened files on Mac OS X

Tags: browser, osx-yosemite, temporary-files

I'm using Mac OS X Yosemite on my MacBook Pro and a Firefox web browser. Every time that I open some file on the web, it saves a copy on my desktop folder, even if I'm not interested on keep it. There is some way to send all those files to the /temp dir?

Answer (score 0):

With Firefox active, click `Firefox -> Preferences` on the menu bar.  Under `General` there is an option to set the default download directory.